# How could I refactor this bit of code here to achieve the same result?

Tags: java, android, refactoring

I am working on an app for school. I was looking through the code and found this thing I made:

```
if (answerTxt1.getText().toString().matches("")) {
        infoStatus.setText("Answer1 cannot be empty!");
        return;
   } else if (answerTxt2.getText().toString().matches("")){
        infoStatus.setText("Answer2 cannot be empty!");
        return;
   } else if (answerTxt3.getText().toString().matches("")){
        infoStatus.setText("Answer3 cannot be empty!");
        return;
   } else if (answerTxt4.getText().toString().matches("")){
       infoStatus.setText("Answer4 cannot be empty!");
       return;
    }
```

The idea behind this 'logic' is that there are 4 slots to write on the app but none can't be empty. If one of them is empty, a textView named infoStatus will display the message about the Exception ocurred.

I know this can have a refactor and can be done in less lines but I am not sure how. So far my idea was this:

```
if (answerTxt1.getText().toString().matches("") 
             || answerTxt2.getText().toString().matches("")
             || answerTxt3.getText().toString().matches("")
             || answerTxt4.getText().toString().matches("")) {

       infoStatus.setText("One of the answers is empty!");
       return;
    }
```

but I won't get the specific message for the user of which answerTxt# is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android - how to create a reusable function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603412/android-how-to-create-a-reusable-function)

Comment: Aside from removing the duplication, `.isEmpty()` is an easier way to check if a string is empty.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava No, it does not. Because it is not about creating a function but refactoring this into something more clean and less redundant.

Comment: @WhiteGlove ..and that would be done without a function, how?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Perhaps if I store every TextView object into an array and iterate through it I could reduce the thing into 4 lines and would be less redundant. I'm just asking for possible solutions but ppl just downvotes with ease :(

Comment: @user85421 I use toString() just to access the String methods such as matches().

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a code review rather than about a specific issue.  This question may be on-topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but please review [what types of questions are on-topic in that community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Comment: @RyanM Thank you for your answer. I did not know the existence of this community for code review. I will post there from now on if I ever have a similar issue. Although my question there would qualify to perfomance (after reading the on-topic questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as

```
TextView[] textViews = {answerTxt1, answerTxt2, answerTxt3, answerTxt1};
for(int i=0; i<textViews.length; i++){
    if(textViews[i].getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        infoStatus.setText("Answer"+ (i+1) + " cannot be empty!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a method that checks if an arbitrary text view is empty, and sets the error field if it is, like this:

```
boolean checkEmpty(TextView textView, String name) {
   if (textView.getText().length() == 0) {
        infoStatus.setText(name + " cannot be empty!");
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then you can get rid of most of the duplication in your code:

```
if (checkEmpty(answerTxt1, "answerTxt1")) {
    return;
}
if (checkEmpty(answerTxt2, "answerTxt2")) {
    return;
}
...
```

You can go even further by creating data structures to hold your text views and error messages, but it will come with the cost of making the code more complex, rigid, and brittle.

Comment: You could even do `checkEmpty(...) || checkEmpty(...)` etc in the condition.

Comment: Prefer a `@StringRes int res` as second argument for localization.

Comment: Or `Arrays.asList(new Pair(tv1, stringRes), new Pair(tv2, stringRes)).stream().allMatch(this::checkEmpty);` if you change the method signature of `checkEmpty(Pair<TextView, Integer> pair)`

Comment: @MarkKeen Could you please elaborate an answer for that? I think that is what I expected from this question.